# grok match : parse log file for time only using pattern or match

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I want to parse the below mentioned line from log file.

> 03:34:19,491  INFO [:sm-secondary-17]: DBBackup:106 - The max_allowed_packet value defined in  [16M] does not match the value from /etc/mysql/my.cnf [24M].  The value will be used.

After parse, the output must be :

```
Time :  03:34:19
LogType : INOF
Message : [:sm-secondary-17]: DBBackup:106 - The max_allowed_packet value defined in  [16M] does not match the value from /etc/mysql/my.cnf [24M].  The value will be used.
```

Ignore : ,491 (comma and 3 digit number).

Comment: Show us some efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grok filter config should be like this for parsing the mentioned log.

```
...
filter {
    grok {
        match => {"message" => "%{TIME:Time},%{NUMBER:ms} %{WORD:LogType} %{GREEDYDATA:Message}"}
        remove_field => [ "ms" ]
    }
}
...
```

Comment: This is working and also i found one more solution : %{TIME:time}  %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:message}

Comment: That's good. Just for my knowledge, let me know does the milliseconds are captured in Time field?

Comment: @HatimStovewala, TIME is defined using HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND, and SECOND is defined such that it should include milliseconds.